# unable to clear my sharedPreferences using editor.clear().commit();

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, android-activity, sharedpreferences

I am working on an android project where I have a scenario such as :

I used place picker.and data that place picker gave is sent to different activities using shared preference.and show this data in TextView.

but the problem is when I closed activity and again open that activity; my data still visible in TextView.

even when I cleared it in onDestroy().

**here is my code for send data :**

```
 SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("address", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
 editor.putString("address", (String) Address);
 editor.commit();
 finish();
```

**here is my code to set and clear data:**

```
 @Override
protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("address", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    String n = settings.getString("name", "");
    String a = settings.getString("address", "");
    name.setText(n);
    location.setText(a);
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("address", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.remove("address");
    editor.clear().commit();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

**here is my preference manager class :**

```
   public class PrefManager {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    // shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    // Shared preferences file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "sara";

    private static final String IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH = "IsFirstTimeLaunch";

    public PrefManager(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    public void setFirstTimeLaunch(boolean isFirstTime) {
        editor.putBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, isFirstTime);
        editor.clear().commit();
    }

    public boolean isFirstTimeLaunch() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_FIRST_TIME_LAUNCH, true);
    }
}
```

**And please don't mark this question as duplicate because I see every related questions and see answers. I tried every possible solutions but nothing worked for me. I am new to android so please help me.**

Comment: Have you checked your onDestroy() method is getting called or not?

Comment: Try to shift code from `onDestroy` to `onStop`

Comment: @HarshJatinder still facing same problem

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where you are using `SharedPreference` object to set data in it. But I guess this is the problem:

1. In this activity, you are clearing `SharedPreferenece` correctly.
2. You go back to previous `Activity`. And the previous activity, sets data to shared preference, **again**. So **SharedPreference** is not empty anymore.
3. You go to second activity (which you remove shared preference data in `onDestroy()`). As shared preference is not empty, you are seeing data again.

So check the code again and feel free to ask any questions.

Comment: I'm using `SharedPreference` object to set data in `onResume()` method

Comment: @BlackCoder Yes I see that. But I'm asking where are you setting data in `SharedPreference`?

Answer (score 0):

Try check the logs to make sure you are really going 'onDestory' well.

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Log.d("address", "onDestory");

    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("address", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.remove("address");
    editor.clear().commit();
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

There is no problem with the code for creating and removing SharedPreferences.